# Zend Error on godaddy server

Tags: zend-framework

I am not used to the Zend Framework, I am changing my server to godaddy hosting, also I have changed the domain namme. After uploading files I am getting this error on www.abc.com while on other host it was working fine.

My root directory looks like:

```
application
htdocs
library
-Zend
```

Please help me with this error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/37/10289737/html/index.php on line 17
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path=':.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/37/10289737/html/index.php on line 17
```

My index.php file looks like this

```
<?php
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
  || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?              getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

  // Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
get_include_path(),
 )));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
 $application = new Zend_Application(
APPLICATION_ENV,
   APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
   );

     $options = $application->getOptions();
       $db = Zend_Db::factory($options['resources']['db']['adapter'], array(
'host' => $options['resources']['db']['params']['host'],
 'username' => $options['resources']['db']['params']['username'],
 'password' => $options['resources']['db']['params']['password'],
   'dbname' => $options['resources']['db']['params']['dbname']
     ));

//$db=Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

$db->beginTransaction();
   $sql = file_get_contents(APPLICATION_PATH . '/data/data.sql');
 $db->query($sql);
 $db->commit();

 $application->bootstrap()
   ->run();
```

And I am unable to locate the `php.ini` file.

Comment: is there a file at `library/Zend/Application.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add path to your include_path:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Look, this is from your error info:

```
include_path=':.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php'
```

so code below is not working

```
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library')
```

Where is your index.php file? In htdocs directory?
Maybe godaddy dont gives permission for php scripts to access files under htdocs?

Comment: so i have moved the index.php file at root folder, Do i need to move all the files from htdocs

Comment: please try to var_dump(realpath(dirname(_____FILE_____))); at beginning of index.php and post result here. I will try to help you to fix it ;)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/37/10289737/html/index.php on line 4

Comment: in wich line are you using var_dump()? in 4th?

Comment: <?php                                                                    
                  var_dump(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)))
                  // Define path to application directory
                   defined('APPLICATION_PATH')

Comment: 1st line use this
<?php var_dump(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))); exit; ?> Remember to add double '_' before FILE and after

Comment: string(30) "/home/content/37/10289737/html"